# What's an efficient way to store a grid with frame origins into core data?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have a gird of subview subviews. Each subview contains an image, rect, x any y origins, width and height, etc.. I am starting to work with core data and I'm not really seeing a good way to save the grid. The only way that I can think of doing this is when I go to save the grid, to get origin.x, origin.y, width, height, etc.. and store each one of those individual values. Then when i go to load the grid from core data, recreate the grid with all of those values. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `NSStringFromgCGRect()` and `CGRectFromString()` and then it's obvious that you also can store the 4 values (x,y,w,h) within one string field.
I would go for that way.